# i have a html form. And i want my output to be in excel sheet. Please suggest want i have to do. PHP

Tags: php, forms

i have a html form. And i want my output to be in excel sheet. Please suggest want i have to do. PHP.

Comment: Has been answered numerous times before. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
// We'll be outputting a Excel
header('Content-type: application/xls');

// It will be called Test.xls
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Test.xls"');

echo "some Excel data";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can output the values as plain text with fields separated with a character like `;` and import that in Excel as CSV.